# RegEx: Match same string into 2 named groups

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following C# code:

```
string MyString = "<a href=\"magnet:?xt=urn:btih:7f3befa467c4cac0787286c87ea264a0606066f5&dn=some.file.name.zip&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.istole.it%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.ccc.de%3A80\" title=\"Download this torrent using magnet\">...</a>[Some unwanted stuff here]<a href=[Another]>";

MatchCollection MyMatches = Regex.Matches(MyString, "(?<URL>magnet:\\?.*?)(?:\"|')");           
foreach(Match MyMatch in MyMatches)
{
    MessageBox.Show(MyMatch.Groups["URL"].Value);
}
```

My question is: how can I also put `&dn=some.file.name.zip` into a named group called `<File>`?

Comment: To parse htmls you can use `HtmlAgilityPack`, to parse url, you have the `Uri` and `HttpUtility` classes.

Comment: @L.B HtmlAgilityPack is overkill for this particular scenario; but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string MyString = "<a href=\"magnet:?xt=urn:btih:7f3befa467c4cac0787286c87ea264a0606066f5&dn=some.file.name.zip&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.istole.it%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.ccc.de%3A80\" title=\"Download this torrent using magnet\">...</a>[Some unwanted stuff here]<a href=[Another]>";

MatchCollection MyMatches = Regex.Matches(MyString, "(?<URL>magnet:\\?.*(&dn=(?<File>[^&]+)).*?)(?:\"|')");           
foreach(Match MyMatch in MyMatches)
{
    MessageBox.Show(MyMatch.Groups["URL"].Value);
    MessageBox.Show(MyMatch.Groups["File"].Value);
}
```